# C++ passing file lines to a vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, function, vector, user-input

my code is supposed to pass the information in a txt file to a string vector then ask the user for input and compare it to the string vector to see if there is any match. For some reason when I input a line thats on the input file it does not match it with the string vector. Here is my code

thank you in advance

```
/*You are going to keep track of user majors using a vector.

First read in the file:

http://www.freerschool.com/pluginfile.php/9623/mod_resource/content/1/MajorsFull.txt

Enter each major into a vector of strings.

Ask the user to keep entering in possible majors until they enter "quit" or "Quit".

Create a function:

bool checkMajor(string userInput)

that takes in the major from the user (as a string) and returns true if the major is in the list of possible majors and a false if the major is not there.

Display to the screen whether or not the major they entered is available in the file of majors.

Hint:

for(string line; getline( input, line ); )
{
 //Read in the line into the vector!
}*/
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool checkMajor(string userInput, vector<string>majorsFull){
    bool answer = true;
    string major;
    for(int i = 0; i < majorsFull.size(); i++){
        if (majorsFull[i] == userInput){
                answer = true;
                break;
        }
        else answer = false;
    }
    return answer;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open ("MajorsFull.txt");

    vector<string> majorsFull;
    string userInput;

    for (string majors; getline(infile, majors);){
        majorsFull.push_back(majors);
    }

    do

    {

    getline(cin, userInput);

    if (userInput != "Quit" && userInput != "quit"){


    if (checkMajor(userInput, majorsFull))
    {
            cout << "Yes" << endl;
    }

    else cout << "No" << endl;

    }

    else break;

    }


    while (userInput != "Quit" && userInput != "quit");

    infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a few lines of what the file contains:

```
Accounting
Accounting
Actuarial Science
Advertising
Advertising
African American and African Studies
African American and African Studies
Agribusiness Management
"Agricultural, Food and Resource Economics"
"Agricultural, Food and Resource Economics"
Animal Science
Animal Science
Animal Science
Animal Science-Environmental Toxicology
Anthropology
Anthropology
Applied Engineering Sciences
Applied Mathematics
Applied Mathematics
Applied Spanish Linguistics
Applied Statistics
Arabic
Art Education
Art History and Visual Culture
Arts and Humanities
Astrophysics
Astrophysics and Astronomy
Astrophysics and Astronomy
```

Comment: It doesn't match anything even tho I am putting exactly whats on the txt file

Comment: Could you post a few sample lines of what the file contains?

Comment: Just posted a few lines from the txt

Comment: If you keep writing your if/else statements like that you're going to make a mistake one day and it will be a nightmare to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: In `checkMajor` you need to exit the loop when you find the answer else you will likely end up returning false.

Comment: I already did with a break after it evaluates the comparison and assigns answer to true if it matches... still doesn't wok

Comment: It works for me.  It has to match perfectly.

Comment: @Duck take a look at my code I have already changed it to have a break after assigning answer to true

Comment: I would default answer to false but it shouldn't matter and the code is otherwise correct.  Step through it with a debugger.  It should be working unless you are spelling the input wrong or something like that.

Comment: Its working now... I had to redo the input file as it seems it had the wrong format

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in `checkMajor()` you continue to go over the possible answers even after you found that the user entered an answer that exists in the file, so your `for` loop should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < majorsFull.size(); i++){
    if (majorsFull[i] == userInput) return true;
}

return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the function below,I have fixed it.In your code,it always return false if the last line do not match.

```
bool checkMajor(string userInput, vector<string>majorsFull){
    bool answer;
    string major;
    for(int i = 0; i < majorsFull.size(); i++){
        if (majorsFull[i] == userInput) return answer = true;
        //else answer = false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: For some reason it still gives me the same answer

Comment: I also tried exactly the last line of the txt file and it didn't working

Comment: But it works when I try,using the last line,and exactly your code.Oh,that is not the problem.When the for loop find it match,it shoud stop.

Comment: I already tried with a break after setting answer to true but still doesn't work

Comment: I try "Accounting
Yes
Arts and Humanities
Yes
Astrophysics and Astronomy d
No
"Agricultural, Food and Resource Economics"
Yes
Agricultural, Food and Resource Economics
No" it work.I think your original code is right . Did you differentiate UPPERCASE and LOWERCASE?